# Find Armstrong numbers in java

Tags: java

I found all these numbers, but I can't understand why in my code, the direction of the cycle decides everything
When he goes from 9999 to 100 he does not count numbers less than 1000
And when the cycle goes from 100 to 9999 then everything works from beginning to end...
Code that works:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n  , po = 0, count = 0;
        double arm;
        int[] elems = {0,0,0,0};
        for(int i = 100; i < 9999; i++){
            for( n = i;n >= 1; count++){
                elems[count] = n%10;
                n /= 10;
                po++;
            }
            arm = pow(elems[0],po)+pow(elems[1],po)+pow(elems[2],po)+pow(elems[3],po);
            if(arm == i ){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            po = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
```

And code that does NOT work:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n  , po = 0, count = 0;
        double arm;
        int[] elems = {0,0,0,0};
        for(int i = 9999; i > 100; i--){
            for( n = i;n >= 1; count++){
                elems[count] = n%10;
                n /= 10;
                po++;
            }
            arm = pow(elems[0],po)+pow(elems[1],po)+pow(elems[2],po)+pow(elems[3],po);
            if(arm == i ){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            po = 0;
            count = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
9474
8208
1634
```

As you can see, the difference is only in the direction of the cycle ... Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that all `elems` are overwritten each time before `arm = pow(...` is evaluated? (Edit: Answer is no) Reset the array, too, on each iteration.

Comment: Very interesting mathematically ... and agree with Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added: Arrays.fill(elems,0);

```
 public static void armstrong() {
    int n  , po = 0, count = 0;
    double arm;
    int[] elems = {0,0,0,0};
    for(int i = 9999; i > 100; i--){
        for( n = i;n >= 1; count++){
            elems[count] = n%10;
            n /= 10;
            po++;
        }
        arm = pow(elems[0],po)+pow(elems[1],po)+pow(elems[2],po)+pow(elems[3],po);

        if(arm == i ){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        //added
        Arrays.fill(elems, 0);
        po = 0;
        count = 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not all `elems` elements are overwritten for `i < 1000` so the previous content remains when `arm = pow(...` is evaluated.

Reset the `elems` for each iteration of the outer `for`-loop as well.